# Pythonic way to "flatten" object hierarchy to nested dicts?

Tags: python

I need to "flatten" objects into nested dicts of the object's properties. The objects I want to do this with are generally just containers for basic types or other objects which act in a similar way. For example:

```
class foo(object):
    bar = None
    baz = None

class spam(object):
    eggs = []

x = spam()
y = foo()
y.bar = True
y.baz = u"boz"
x.eggs.append(y)
```

What I need to "flatten" this to is:

```
{ 'eggs': [ { 'bar': True, 'baz': u'boz' } ] }
```

Is there anything in the stdlib which can do this for me? If not, would I have to test `isinstance` against all known base-types to ensure I don't try to convert an object which can't be converted (eg: bool)?

**Edit:**

These are objects are being returned to my code from an external library and therefore I have no control over them. I could use them as-is in my methods, but it would be easier (safer?) to convert them to dicts - especially for unit testing.

Comment: I think the only way to solve this is to write a base class supporting serialization by iterating over it's own member variables. I'm not sure if this is what you intend but If so I would be happy to provide an example implementation.

Comment: Can you give us the use case? It may be there is a more Pythonic way to approach the overall problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code:** You may need to handle other iterable types though:

```
def flatten(obj):
    if obj is None:
        return None
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__') and obj.__dict__:
        return dict([(k, flatten(v)) for (k, v) in obj.__dict__.items()])
    elif isinstance(obj, (dict,)):
        return dict([(k, flatten(v)) for (k, v) in obj.items()])
    elif isinstance(obj, (list,)):
        return [flatten(x) for x in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, (tuple,)):
        return tuple([flatten(x) for x in obj])
    else:
        return obj
```

**Bug?**
In your code instead of:

```
class spam(object):
    eggs = []

x = spam()
x.eggs.add(...)
```

please do:

```
class spam(object):
    eggs = None #// if you need this line at all though

x = spam()
x.eggs = []
x.eggs.add(...)
```

If you do not, then all instances of `spam` will share the same `eggs` list.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in the standardlib. Yes, you would have to somehow test that the types are basic types like str, unicode, bool, int, float, long...

You could probably make a registry of methods to "serialize" different types, but that would only be useful if you have some types that should not have all it's attributes serialized, for example, or if you also need to flatten class attributes, etc.

Comment: exactly what I wrote in my comment but you don't necessarily need to check for basic types, when your extended types support some kind of serialization method.
Just try to call it on every type and catch the appropriate exception for base types.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every object has a dictionary (called `__dict__`), with all its methods and members.
With some type checking, you can then write a function that filters out only the members you are interested in.

It is not a big task, but as chrispy said, it could worth to try looking at your problem from a completely different perspective.

Comment: Thanks, but these are objects I'm being passed from another library so have no control over them. I could use them as-is in my methods, but it would be easier to convert them to dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very proud of this, but is possible to do the following:

1. Create a super class that has the serialization method and loop through its properties.
2. At runtime extend your classes using **bases** at runtime
3. Execute the class from the new super class. It should be able to access the **dict** data from the children and work.

Here is an example:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None
        self.baz = None

class spam(object):
    delf __init__(self):
       self.eggs = []

class Serializable():
    def serialize(self):
       result = {}
       for property in self.__dict__.keys():
           result[property] = self.__dict__[property]
       return result
foo.__bases__ += (Serializable,)
spam.__bases__ += (Serializable,)

x = spam()
y = foo()
y.bar = True
y.baz = u"boz"
x.eggs.append(y)
y.serialize()
```

Things to point out. If you do not set the var is init the **dict** willnot work 'cause it is accessing the instance variables not the class variables (I suppose you meant instance ones). Second, make sure Serializable DOES NOT inherit from object, it is does you will have a 

`TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution`

Hope it helps!

Edit: If you are just copying the **dict** use the deepcopy module, this is just an example :P